# Dash/Ploty line graph - Callback failed: Server did not respsond

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm learning DASH by building an app which grabs data from Finnhub.io via API and plots it.

I'm currently getting this problem when I change the input for the dash callback. It happens intermittently, and after a couple of refreshes it appears to work fine. However I would prefer if it would work off the bat 100%.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4WPu.png)

I've tried diagnosing the problem, and the error seems to appear at line 99 of:

`fig = px.line(df1, x = df1.index , y ="c")` - data is indexed in date time and "c" is the column name of the closing price of the stock as fetched.

[SS of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hccbm.png)

I was wondering if anyone was having a same/similar issue or could assist.

Thank you very very much in advance!